# How to replace a particular string in js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I have a variable with the following data

Peaks in mesothelioma incidence were expected to take place between 2014 and 2021 in Australia, between 2011 and 2015 in the United Kingdom, between 2015 and 2024 in Italy, in 2010 in the United States, in 2015 in Denmark, in 2017 in the Netherlands, and in 2027 in Japan.

Here I want to replace

```
<img src="test" />
```

To

```
<amp-img src="test"></amp-img>
```

But here I am getting the data of 100 records as an example I put

```
 <img src="test" />
```

But I am not sure what my img tag contains.So I van replace img with

```
replace('<img',<amp-img>);
```

But how can I replace the end tag i.e

```
  ('/>','></amp-img>').
```

Can any one please suggest me help.Thanks.

Comment: How about just chaining another `replace` at the end like `str.replace('img', 'amp-img').replace('/>', '</amp-img>')`?

Comment: @Andrew,I may have so many '/>' tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method roughly;

```
$("amp-img").replaceWith("<img src=\"test\"/>");
```

http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Answer (score 0):

With regards to this...

> ...
>
> ```
> <img src="test" />
> ```
>
> *But I am not sure what my img tag contains.So I van replace img with*
>
> ```
> replace('<img',<amp-img>);
> ```
>
> ...

The [JavaScript String Replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method takes two arguments, the first being either a Regular Expression or an exact string, and the second taking a replacement string or function.  If you only need to make one specifc change then using strings as both arguments is the way to go, and multiple 'replacers' can be chained for more complex operations.

So this...

```
var sampleString = '<img src="test" />';
```

..can be 'replaced' like so...

```
var newString = sampleString.replace('<img','<amp-img')
                            .replace(' />','</amp-img>');
```

The `newString` variable now contains the changes you just made to the contents of the `sampleString` variable.

Hope that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

This will replace the very last closing tag with what you want:

```
sampleString.replace(sampleString.slice(sampleString.lastIndexOf(' />')), '></amp-img>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you have is a string that literally includes: `<img src="test" />` then you can use:

```
string = string.replace(/<img\s+(.*?)\s*\/>/g, '<amp-img $1></amp-img>');
```

or even:

```
string = string.replace(/<img\s+([^>]*?)\s*\/>/g, '<amp-img $1></amp-img>');
```

Don't replace the closing tag separately as suggested here:

```
string.replace(' />','</amp-img>')
```

because that will break all other markup where you have other tags that you don't want to replace (and in that case it will also not work if you have no space before the slash - which is completely valid and should be expected).

If what you have is a DOM object then you should replace the DOM nodes individually instead of parsing the markup as strings.